# What is default flink watermark strategy for kafka source connector?

Tags: apache-flink

From [this documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#event-time-and-watermarks) I can read following:

> By default, the record will use the timestamp embedded in Kafka ConsumerRecord as the event time. You can define your own WatermarkStrategy for extract event time from the record itself, and emit watermark downstream:
>
> ```
> env.fromSource(kafkaSource, new CustomWatermarkStrategy(), "Kafka Source With Custom Watermark Strategy")
> ```
>
> [This documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/) describes details about how to define a WatermarkStrategy.

What Watermark strategy is used if user doesn't provide the optional one?

I'm asking, because I found that default is empty [in the source code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java#L140).

We are running Flink 1.11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no default watermark strategy. If you don't provide one there will be no watermarks.

Comment: thnx, so what is the impact of no watermarks? I assumed they are required for checkpoints/savepoints to work ( this can't be true, since system is generating checkpoints just fine )

Comment: The only role that watermarks play is to trigger event-time timers. Event-time timers can be used in process functions, and are used internally by windows, and by interval and temporal joins. Otherwise watermarks are unnecessary, and they play no role in checkpointing.

Comment: On one of our flink apps (v1.11), i'm using "timeWindow()" method (source is kinesis) and it works - window is evaluated whenever the time specified in the method's argument expires, without any watermarking strategies being defined. On flink v1.13 however "timeWindow" seems to be deprecated,  and it doesn't emit any records if watermarking strategy is not explicitly defined. Is that expected or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `timeWindow` used to default to processing time windowing, unless explicitly configured otherwise. And processing time windows don't require a watermark strategy. Then the default was changed to event time, which requires watermarks.